# Выводится неправильная длина строки

Tags: rust

Скажите пожалуйста почему код:

```
let mut compiled_string: String = String::new();
std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut compiled_string).ok();
println!("{}", compiled_string.chars().count());
```

В любой ситуации выводит длину на 2 символа больше чем есть на самом деле?

Comment: А как `&mut string` связан с `compiled_string`?

Comment: @u_mulder, это опечатка там все одна строка.

Comment: Под виндами пробуешь? Видимо в конце строки `\r\n`?

Comment: @ДмитрийКолесник, определённости ради «в любой ситуации» это в какой иммено?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, в плане размер всегда больше на 2 не зависимо от размера строки

Comment: @ДмитрийКолесник, ты вряд ли проверил __все__ возможные строки, чтобы утверждать что это «всегда так»…  какие именно строки вводишь и что именно выдаёт rust? может ты исключительно какой-то текст с какой-то странной диактрикой вводишь, а может быть забыл про конец строки и про то что на win он состоит из двух символов, как говорит **u_mulder**…

Comment: В винде строки заканчиваются символами с кодом 10, 13. В линуксе - кодом 10. Очевидно, это они и есть. Распечатайте коды символов всех символов - будет понятно, где лишние. С другой стороны, юникод - сложная штука, в которой один символ может занимать больше одного char. Там есть всякие суррогаты, ударения, и тд и тп. В 99% случаев на это можно просто забить.

Comment: @chabapok, да вы были правы. Строка заканчивается номерами символов 13 и 10.